# Why an insufficient overlap cause vanishing exchange interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, ferromagnetism, exchange-interaction

Why should the exchange interaction vanish if the atoms do not have sufficient overlap in their overfunctions? For exchange interaction not to vanish, the only requirement seems to be that the exchange integral be nonzero. I don't get the relation of exchange interaction with overlap of wavefunctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint :}$ Exchange interaction between two electrons with same spin in two spatial orbitals $\phi_{\alpha}^{}(\vec{r})$ ($\alpha=1,2$) is $$J \propto \int_{\vec{r}_{1}^{} \in \mathbb{R}_{}^{3}}^{}d_{}^{3}\vec{r}_{1}^{}\int_{\vec{r}_{2}^{} \in \mathbb{R}_{}^{3}}^{}d_{}^{3}\vec{r}_{2}^{}\left[\phi_{1}^{*}(\vec{r}_{1}^{})\phi_{2}^{}(\vec{r}_{1}^{})\right]_{}^{*}\frac{1}{|\vec{r}_{1}^{}-\vec{r}_{2}^{}|}\left[\phi_{1}^{*}(\vec{r}_{2}^{})\phi_{2}^{}(\vec{r}_{2}^{})\right]_{}^{}.$$ Argue what happens to   $\left[\phi_{1}^{*}(\vec{r}_{}^{})\phi_{2}^{}(\vec{r}_{}^{})\right]_{}^{}$ when the two wave-functions don't have common region of appreciable magnitude.